# Importing a .csv file into java, splitting it to an array or strings

Tags: java, string, arraylist

As the title says, I have imported a csv file with 3 columns separated by a comma (,).
When I try to print each column on it's own, the first column prints without problems. When I try the second and third columns (index [1] and [2]), they print as expected but I get an "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" error at the end of the program before exiting. Why is that?

Here is the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String path = "C:\\Users\\UserONE\\Downloads\\inSic1.csv";
        String line = "";

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            String value [] = line.split(",");
            System.out.println(value[1]);
```

Comment: Maybe there is an "empty line" at the end of your csv?

Comment: Good. Nevertheless, you should try to avoid these problems by checking the array size (or the String size) before trying to access your array via a fixed index.

Comment: As an alternative, you could `readAllLines(Path path)` and receive a `List<String>` (using `java.nio`). Then you can investigate this list **after** the io processing. You could split every item in that list and check its size as @maloomeister already stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try printing the values dynamically and not with a hardcoded value.
E.g.

```java
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            String values[] = line.split(",");
            for(String val: values)
            {
                System.out.println(val);
            }
        }
```

This way you will not reach an index that does not exist and you generify the problem, even if you use another file, it will work.